# How can I generate seperate logs for different HTML URL paths?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, apache2

I'm trying to breakout the logging of my website based on directory access, so I'm seeking an elaboration to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1460790/32836) (or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10001437/32836) too): In which file do place the suggested answer?

I put the following in my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (actually via an `Include my-logging.conf`):

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/download/.+$" download_access
CustomLog /home/jamie/apache-logs/download.log common env=download_access
```

The directory `/home/jamie/apache-logs/` and the files therein are universally writable, but when I access the resource via my browser (`http://download/index.html`) the main access log (`/var/log/access.log`) is updated but not the log I was hoping would be: `/home/jamie/apache-logs/download.log` remains untouched.

I'm reasonably certain `mod_setenvif` is already enabled:

```
$ sudo a2enmod setenvif
Module setenvif already enabled
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head Slap!

Regular expression error:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/download/.+$" download_access
```

should be:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/download/.*$" download_access
```

Note the `*` versus the `+`.

Comment: wow... i even looked at that and thought about it for a second, but decided it was fine. lol.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

No, it was the regex. Head slap is right.

---

Have you looked to see if there are places in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` or in the other included sites files (maybe `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/foo.conf` or `/etc/apache2/conf/foo.conf` or something... I use a different distro) that have different **CustomLog**  definitions?

There is more than likely something over-riding your statement. The best place to put the **CustomLog** directive is in the `<VirtualHost>` stanza that defines your site. That way, the directive will have the highest precedence so it will override the server-wide settings. What I think is happening is that your definition is setting a default for the server, but a more specific customlog statement is inside a VirtualHost and overriding it.

Comment: Thanks for responding ... I tried it and nothing.  Aside from the one that I'm trying to enable, there is one `CustomLog` statement in the whole `*.conf` include chain: `CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined`

Comment: try changing `download_access` to `download_access=1`

Comment: Doh! it's my regular expression ... not the answer but +1 for the comments and info provided.